# Where should I put the function setContentView()?

Tags: android, put, setcontentview

I know that the function onCreate() used to construct the activity and UI components but when I try put setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in the function onStart() or onResume(), the UI components apper , that's why?

```
package com.example.E001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(R.layout.demo);  
        Button btn_welcome = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.welcome_msg);
        btn_welcome.setText(R.string.hello_world);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in the onCreate, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

For more info look in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

What I think you are trying to do with the layout.demo is inflate a extra view in your MainActivity.
Then you should NOT use **setContentView()**. For inflating a view in a layout you can use the [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Note: If this does not completely answer your question, than I don't understand your question correctly.